# Xampp MS SQL server PHP 5.6

Tags: php, sql-server, xampp, php-5.6

I have a xampp running with PHP 5.6. Normally I use mysql server, but for a script that already exists i need a MS SQL server.

I searched on the net and installed SQL server 2012.

But now I need the drivers for PHP. Unfornunately I can only find a version that supports 5.4, 5.5..

(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff657782.aspx)

Is there a way to let this work with 5.6?

Comment: maybe you can try and find 3rd party drivers

Comment: I'm even surprised to see an [official 5.4 driver](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlphp/archive/2012/03/23/microsoft-drivers-3-0-1-for-php-for-sql-server-with-php-5-4-support-release.aspx) from March 2012. Much later than that I was totally unable to find such driver :-?

Comment: Latest version 5.10 can be downloaded from here: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/download-drivers-php-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I searched the net for a while.. After posting this question for 10m, I finally found a unofficial driver..

Hope this works, I will check this out..

You can find it on: http://robsphp.blogspot.be/2012/06/unofficial-microsoft-sql-server-driver.html

Comment: This is correct, there is currently no official driver for PHP 5.6. If you care about this, please [upvote this Connect issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/1063175) and hopefully Microsoft will do something about this.

Answer (score 13):

Microsoft recently released a new version (3.2) of the SQL Drivers for PHP which includes compatibility with PHP 5.6.

You can download the drivers here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098

Comment: Try to avoid link-only answers; they are likely to be closed as low-quality. If the link ever changes/moves, your answer is no longer valid, so it is best to add the relevant information from the link in your answer.

Comment: Do you think that my rewording makes the answer acceptable?

Comment: Your answer is fine, I never said it was wrong :P This answer came up in my review tasks, and I simply posted the rules about link-only questions. Looking at the question, it may be hard to answer it otherwise, so I gave you a +1 for this.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it's time to revisit this answer a bit better.
Since you've been pretty clear with your setup. The short answer is placed as steps below

1. Download **ver 3.2** of the SQLSRV drivers from here.
   [https://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=20098](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1lkD.png)
2. Do extract them to your "xampp installation path"\php\ext
3. Kindly ensure you **see and keep** the files : php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll and php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
4. Please delete the redundant files below:

   > ```
   > PHP Drivers License Terms.rtf,
   > php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_nts.dll,
   > php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll,
   > php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_nts.dll,
   > php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll,
   > php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll,
   > php_sqlsrv_54_nts.dll,
   > php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll,
   > php_sqlsrv_55_nts.dll,
   > php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll,
   > php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll,
   > release.txt,
   > SQLSRV_Readme.htm,
   > SQLSRV_ThirdPartyNotices.rtf,
   > ```

   - Place these lines in your php.ini at your "xampp installation path"\php\php.ini
     **extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
     extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll**
   - Restart your XAMPP server and place a '<'?php phpinfo(); ?'>' in an index.php file at \htdocs\'folder'
   - Navigate to it using http://localhost/'folder where phpinfofile is placed'/index.php

If you see something like this image below. It's done, Congratulations[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1lkD.png)

PS : The long answer is here.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296170.aspx

Answer (score 1):

At this time: 
My solution was:

1- Download ver 3.2 of the SQLSRV drivers from here. https://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=20098
[image]

2 Extract the files to your "xampp" folder into the \php\ext

3- Add this lines to php.ini

extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll

extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll

extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll

extension=php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll