# PHP PDO sqlsrv Undefined class constant SQLSRV_ENCODING_UTF8

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdo, sql-server-2012, xampp

I have a Codeigniter 3 app that connects to an SQL Server 2008 database. We setup a new vm with Windows server 2012 r2 64bit, SQL Server Express 2012 and xampp with php 5.6.

We moved the app to it, installed the MSODBC and added the pdo_sqlsrv version 3.2 dll to the extensions folder and loaded it in the ini file, but when we started the app we got this error message:

```
Undefined class constant SQLSRV_ENCODING_UTF8 in pdo_sqlsrv_driver.php on line 144
```

I checked the docs and everything seems right, so we tried reinstalling everything with no luck. What possibly could be the problem?

Comment: Do you have the latest PHP/PDO driver? That constant is defined in Microsoft's library (Windows-based PHP only): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296183%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

For my part, I resolved this by connecting using ODBC instead: http://geekanddummy.com/codeigniter-3-connecting-to-ms-sql-from-linux/

Comment: After more research into it i fixed it by specifying a default tcp port in sql server configuration manager

Comment: Quite a misleading error message, eh!

Comment: I am facing same problem and searching for solution

Comment: I'm too facing the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people searching for a solution for this error, I fixed it by specifying a default TCP port in SQL Server Configuration Manager.

Answer (score 1):

You likely have the wrong PDO driver in your PHP install.  I run PHP/CodeIgniter on several Windows servers, and have run into problems with the wrong drivers when getting things initially setup.

Since you are on PHP 5.6, you need to make sure the  **php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll** OR **php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll** driver is in the PHP `/ext/` directory. Then, in your `php.ini` file, you will need to make sure that both of these extensions are uncommented:

> extension=php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll
>   extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll

Once those two are uncommented, make sure the other references to the SQL Server drivers are commented out.  If that doesn't help, here is another article to check: [Xampp MS SQL server PHP 5.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27126338/xampp-ms-sql-server-php-5-6).

After adjusting the php.ini file, remember to restart the site via IIS.

Comment: This link has the latest DLL files for Windows:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/download-drivers-php-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017