# Connect MS SQL with PHP 5.6 on Centos7

Tags: sql-server, centos7, php-5.6

Im trying to connect a project to an MS SQL but I can't. I read a lot but no one answer helps me.

Now I´m trying with ADOdb with mssql driver but the connection answer is:

Missing extension for mssql

So I suppose I have to install it but I can't find how can do it for PHP 5.6 on Centos. Anyone?

Or maybe other way to reach the DB?

I already tried yum install php56-php-mssql, php56w-mssql but all of them are miss. And yum install php-mssql answer that package
is already installed

**UPDATE**

1) tsql test works

2) php-mssql connection in php also works WHEN RUN FROM THE SHELL

3) running PHP through apache does NOT work.

I found the mssql.so and added the path to my php.ini file, then restarted apache but when I load a page with phpinfo(), mssql.so doesn't show.

What is missing?

Comment: This may be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27126338/xampp-ms-sql-server-php-5-6

Comment: @LaughingVergil first answer is only for windows system, but i gonna try the others

Comment: @LaughingVergil as I supposed, all answer are related to Windows systems. I want to access from PHP 5.6 on Centos7 to a MS SQL on a different machine(Windows OS)

Comment: Do you have another ini file where your extension is not activated?

Comment: @Stony sorry, forget about update. I realized that it works but from php 5.4 installed on server. Running from terminal the php that I use in this domain fails too (PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mssql_connect()). So the problem still being with the php.ini, was not enough add a line and restart apache

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

1) Download PHP5.6 source files.

2) go to php/ext/mssql

3) do phpize but with php used by Plesk located on /opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/phpize

4) configure, make

5) copy generated *.so to extensions folder on /opt/plesk/php/5.6/lib64/php/modules

6) create /opt/plesk/php/5.6/etc/php.d/mssql.ini file with tho following text:

> ; Enable mssql extension module
>
> extension=mssql.so

7) restart apache